# c++ ofstream.put(char) gives weird output

Tags: c++, string, char, put, ofstream

I'm just new to the forums and I am having problems with my c++ script.
I need to output an array of string type to an output txt file.
I have an array, converted it to chars and still problems.
It gives you the first 2 lines, but the rest is either Ì or ¤.
Another problem is the fact that I need to make an endl, put this seems to be impossible with the .put() function.
well here's the core of my program:

```
ofstream ofile ("test2.txt", ios_base::trunc);
i=0;
j=1;
stringstream ss;
char oBoard[9][10];
                    //CHECK WHICH STARTER
if (ofile.is_open()){
    if(board[0][0]=="b"){
        ofile << "black" << endl;
    }
    else{
        ofile << "white" << endl;
    }
                    //START LOOPING FOR OUTPUT
    while(j!=11){
        i=0;
        while(i!=10){
            ss << board[i][j];
            ss >> oBoard[i][j];
            cout << oBoard[i][j] << endl;
            ofile.put(oBoard[i][j]);
            i++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    ofile.close();
}
```

Comment: `c++ script` ? `C++` is ***not*** script language.

Comment: and this is not obviously C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what is the problem to use the `ofile` in the loop with the same syntax, as before the loop?

```
ofile << oBoard[i][j];
```

instead of

```
ofile.put(oBoard[i][j]);
```

Comment: Because that would replace it, instead of adding it, am I right?

Comment: Will replace what? Will add it into the file. Try it.

Comment: OK
I have done what Kiril advised me, and it worked.
But there's another problem. When I run the program, it will either this: Unhandled exception at 0x00000001 in game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
and when I run it without debugging, it will get stuck.
Anyone?

Comment: Post another question for this.